# what string should I use to compare with a mysql entry which is NULL in c

Tags: mysql, c

My problem is that I'm developing a C program which reads integers from a mysql table (which are stored as INT) and do some calculation and INSERT them to another table which is in a another server running ORACLE DB. Here is part of my code I used to do so. Only a code segment is given which I thought has the issue.

```
char sqlPlusString[300];
memset(sqlPlusString, 0, 300);
int i, sum = 0;
int p1_2weeks = 0, p2_1month = 0, p3_2month = 0;
while (row = mysql_fetch_row(result)) {
    int i = 1, sum = 0;
    memset(sqlPlusString, 0, 300);

    for (i = 1; i < 32; i++) {
        if (strcmp(row[i], "NULL") == 0) {
            sum = sum + 0; 
        } else
            sum = sum + strtol(row[i], NULL, 10);
```

hope you could understand what I am saying. The thing is when I try to do this it gives a segmentation fault. I guessed it may be because the comparison gives another result. But it wasn't, It clearly returns a zero when the string "NULL" is there. could there be some other thing to represent NULL values in Mysql DBs. Could someone please explain me.

Comment: What is `row` ? Your debugger will tell you where the crash occurs.

Comment: Not related, but `sum = sum + 0;` doesn't make much sense.

Comment: No I work in the Ubuntu command line. I have no Idea. The command line says only there is a segmentation fault.

Comment: @MichaelWalz yahh. I did it to ignore the value. What you are saying is true. I can omit that line and put a continue.

Comment: How do you know there are 32 results?

Comment: No there are 90 columns. what i am doing is I am taking is the sum of the recent 30 columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot check for `NULL` values in the database by comparing with `"NULL"`.  `NULL` values are actually returned as `NULL` pointers in the corresponding columns.  Modify your code this way:

```
while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(result)) != NULL) {
    int i, sum = 0;
    memset(sqlPlusString, 0, 300);

    for (i = 1; i < 32; i++) {
        if (row[i] != NULL) {
            sum += strtol(row[i], NULL, 10);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Check the manual page http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-fetch-row.html for more details.